# Error format with group_concat in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sample data:

```
table(id, name) with name(varchar(255))
```

with data is

```
table(1, 'test1')
...
     (999, 'test999')
...
```

Query is `Select GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS name FROM table`
And result is `test1test2...test155` => can't get all name of table table, How to fix it ?

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT has its place but don't you just want a select and a loop. the size is limited by the variable "group_concat_max_len" --http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len

Answer (score -1):

try increasing the size of `group_concat_max_len` in your `SESSION` before query as:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```

[MySQL manual for group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len)